# Get position (number) in which a mysql_query was output for a certain value

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having an extremely difficult time trying to find an answer for this. What I want to do is (I think) rather simple, but I can't find any information on it.

Let's say I have a table in my database of fruits, and I'd like to do something like...

```
<?php
require "../body-parts/config.php";

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY name');
$count = 1;
while ($fruit = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $count++ . " ";
echo $fruit['name'] . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Now let's say the output of that is...

1 Apple

2 Cantaloupe

3 Grapes

4 Kiwi

5 Lemon

6 Orange

Now what I would like to do, is grab the number for Kiwi (in this case 4) so that I can use that later... but I don't know how I can do this.

So in short, how is it I grab the number position in which a value was returned? I do not want to echo it out, I simply want to grab it and stick it in a variable so I can use it again.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_kiwi_id = 0;


$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY name');
$count = 1;
while ($fruit = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $count++ . " ";
echo $fruit['name'] . "<br>";
if(strtolower ($fruit['name']) == "kiwi")
$_kiwi_id = $count-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require "../body-parts/config.php";

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY name');

$storage = array();
while ($fruit = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$storage[] = $fruit['name'] . "<br>";
}

//later some point of time
echo $storage[3]['name'] ; //this will echo "kiwi" 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to know how I get the "3" based on the name, rather than the name based on the 3.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array:

```
<?php
require "../body-parts/config.php";

$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM fruits ORDER BY name');
$count = 1;
$fruits = array();
while ($fruit = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  $fruits[$count++] = $fruit['name'];
}

echo $fruits[4]; // prints Kiwi
?>
```

Comment: Arrays are zero based so `echo $fruits[4];` prints "Lemon".